# how do I add an image without getting the background of the UIButton class via Interface Builder?

Tags: ios, ios4, interface-builder, uibutton

I keep getting the white background of the UIButton class and cannot just add the image transparently

Comment: What're you doing exactly right now?

Comment: I make a UIButton (Round REct Button) via IB, which has an all white background.  Then I select the image property to be the image I want.  Image shows up, but the background is all white and ugly.  I want the background to be transparent, or just the dimensions of the image.

Comment: You may want to go through an accept (the outlined check mark) answers that were helpful to you. This is a good way to support the community, thank users who offered helpful answers, and encourage other users to continue answering your questions in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Setting the button `Type` to `Custom` in the Interface Builder should help.

Answer (score 0):

Use `UIButtonTypeCustom` and set the `backgroundImage` of that instead.

Comment: From Object Library, how do I add a UIButtonTypeCustom?  What element do I drag onto the UIToolBar?

Comment: Use a `UIButton`, and then open the Attributes Inspector. Change the option that reads `Round Rect Button` to `Custom Button`.